# Merge [picasa] into [google-picasa]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

There are two tags for Picasa by Google, there should be one, preferably [google-picasa], since people interested in all sorts of Google software can follow them easily using [google*].

Comment: Wouldn't having it as a synonym be a better idea? (Though the way tag synonyms work, might be different of what I think of)